# Not able to pass SendGrid verification with Django

Tags: python, django, sendgrid, django-email

I'm currently reading a book on Django (for beginners) and I reached the point where I need to implement a password reset feature to the test website using [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com) SMTP Relay.

After creating an account and starting to create the SMTP relay I greeted with the following screen:
[image: SendGrid SMTP instruction screen]
Based on this page I added the following lines of code to my *setting.py* file:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxx' #the string which is partialy hidden under the pink square 
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

After running the website and trying to reset my password (the password of the superuser) I get the desired message with the reset link in my console but sadly nothing comes to my email. Thus I get the following error message when trying to verify integration.
[image: Error message]

---

What I tried so far:

- I tried creating multiple different API keys to make sure nothing was wrong with the API key
- I created a new SendGrid account
- I tried removing `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'` from the `settings.py` file (this only made things worst)

I've been trying to solve this issue for over a day now, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't post sensitive passwords on SO! Your sendgrid account is not open to anyone to use as mailing provider.

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you very much for your concern :) Before writing this post I have already disabled the API key

Comment: @dirkgroten that said I just edited out the API from the photos too.

Comment: Is this from your local dev environment or from a production environment?

Comment: @dirkgroten I'm running the code using `python manage.py runserver` so I'm running it locally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your email backend setting is set to use the console. If you're just debugging that's fine, you can see how the emails would look like in the console and copy your password reset link from there.

If you really want to send an email, use the SMTP backend: Set `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'`.

But beware, don't send emails to fake addresses using that, you'll get in trouble if you have too many bounces on your sendgrid account.

Also if you're going to use SendGrid in production, use the API instead of SMTP. django-anymail (but there are also other packages) provides a backend to use the API.

**Update June 2021**
Sendgrid doesn't allow simple username/password authentication anymore (and forces you to login with 2FA). You should use the API, or create an app password specifically for your server and use that instead of your normal password.

Comment: Great, it worked thank you very much. Yea I know about the API I'm just testing the SMTP version right. what's strange is that I see the number of emails increasing in SendGrid right now but I don't seem to receive those emails.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the settings are like they should be, taking into account that you of course don't intend to go into production without securing your info (ie creating environment variables). You *are* going to do this, I assume, but if not, you really, really should consider that.

Also it's these are your actual settings, you should edit this post *right now*. They're supposed to be kept secret, otherwise you're gonna have a real bad day shortly.

Given the nature of your problem, I'm halfway expecting that you're not testing it from a development setting, but rather that you've tried to run it from production. It is also my suspicion, that you're using Pythonanywhere or Heroku with a free account. Let me know if I'm all wrong here :)

The skinny is this: Without coughing up those $5, those two providers (and other providers add well, I presume) won't let you use sendgrid.

If I'm assuming wrongly, I'd appreciate seeing the views.py that handles the sending of email.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I have already disabled those keys before writing this post (just to make sure I just edited them out from the question too). I'm testing the website using `python manage.py runserver` so the reset link look something like this "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/password_reset/" . Doesn't SendGrid offer 100 free daily emails?

Comment: Yes, they do. 10,000 during the 1st month, and then they throttle down to 100 after that.